# Objective-C: variable optimized away by compiler

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, compiler-construction, gdb

I am trying to run the following code:

```
1. NSURL *checkLicenseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"check_license.php?accesskey=&license_key="];
// call server API
2. NSError *err = nil;
3. NSXMLDocument *xmlResult = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:checkLicenseURL options:NSXMLDocumentTidyXML error:&err];
```

But when looking at variables in gdb, after line 1 was executed, doing

```
p checkLicenseURL
```

returns

```
$1 = <variable optimized away by compiler>
```

It also causes line 3 to crash. Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just compile without optimizations turned on, or select a "debug" build if you used a wizard of some sort to build your project.  I'm not sure where to turn off optimizations in XCode but you probably want these GCC command line options for debugging:

```
-O0 -fno-inline
```

Comment: I'm using the "debug" mode in Xcode, but it is still giving this error.

Answer (score 5):

Turning off optimizations for everything is one option. It is also possible to instruct the compiler that particular variables should not be optimized away. The way to do it is with the `volatile` keyword:

```
volatile NSURL *checkLicenseURL = ...
```

[Wikipedia entry on volatile variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable)

Another similar question: [iPhone Variable Optimized Away by Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942840/iphone-variable-optimized-away-by-compiler)