# Why is Xcode/LLVM optimising out the variable this method returns when compiling for ARM64

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arm, llvm, compiler-optimization

> This is a known bug and is has been submitted to [bugreporter.apple.com](http://bugreporter.apple.com) under bug id **#16040090**
>
> **NB:** This issue only reproducible on a 64-bit (A7) iOS device. If run in the simulator or on a 32-bit device it works fine.
>
> **Please note:** This bug seems to be fixed in LLVM 5.1, this is the default compiler for Xcode 5.1 (currently in beta).

I have a method `-pointValue` (see below), it works fine when compiled with the optimisation level set to `-O0`, but using `-Os` (the default for Release builds) the compiler optimises out the line that sets the variable `point`. `point` is used as the return value so any other method calling this gets random values.

The issue can be fixed by declaring the `points` variable as `volatile`. However, why does the compiler think it can remove the line setting `points`? Is it something to do with how I have written the method?

```
- (CGPoint)pointValue
{
    ULongLong encodedPoint = [self unsignedLongLongValue];
    ULongLong *values = [self splitEncodedInteger:encodedPoint withShift:SHIFT];
    
    //volatile is required to prevent optimising out
    volatile CGPoint point = CGPointMake(values[0], values[1]);
    
    free(values); //clean up
    
    return point;
}
```

**NB:** `-splitEncodedInteger:withShift:` uses malloc() to create a 2 element array that is retuned and then this memory is `free`'d by the callee.

*As requested, the code for `-splitEncodedInteger:withShift:`*

```
- (ULongLong *)splitEncodedInteger:(ULongLong)encocedInteger withShift:(int)shiftValue
{
    ULongLong *splitFloats = malloc(sizeof(ULongLong) * 2);
    
    splitFloats[0] = (encocedInteger >> shiftValue);
    splitFloats[1] = encocedInteger - ((encocedInteger >> shiftValue) << shiftValue);
    
    return splitFloats;
}
```

Full [source code](https://github.com/rjstelling/cgtype-encoding) of the encode categories can be [found on GitHub](https://github.com/rjstelling/cgtype-encoding).

### Example project

As requested by several commenters I have created a [simple test project](https://github.com/rjstelling/cgtype-encoding/tree/clang-optimisation-bug). <strike>However, even after setting all the build settings to match the original project I myself *cannot* reproduce the issue.</strike> The bug only shows up **on device**.

The only thing I can see different is when the project is run with full optimisation on, LLDB can read some of the variables, and trying to print them to the console I get this:

```
(CGSize) size = <no location, value may have been optimized out>
```

This is exactly what I get with my failing project but in that instance passing around one of these "optimised out" variables just gives random data (resulting in massive views being created [or failing to be created]).

Below are screen shots of the example app running with -O0 and -Ofast respectively.

[image: Example app running with -O0]
[image: Expanded -O0]

*Example app running with -O0 (no optimisations), you can see info on the variables*

[image: Example app running with -Ofast]
[image: Expanded -Ofast]

*Example app running with -Ofast (full optimisations), you **cannot** see info on the variables*

#### Running on device

This is the output when running ton device with *optimisations off*:

```
2014-02-10 11:36:00.771 optimisation-bug[461:60b] *** Compiling with no optmisations, the code should work as expected ***
2014-02-10 11:36:00.773 optimisation-bug[461:60b] encodedRect: 50332672
2014-02-10 11:36:00.774 optimisation-bug[461:60b] encodedSize: 45089712
2014-02-10 11:36:00.775 optimisation-bug[461:60b] encodePoint: 2621480
2014-02-10 11:36:05.629 optimisation-bug[461:60b] rect: {{0, 0}, {768, 1024}}
2014-02-10 11:36:06.099 optimisation-bug[461:60b] size: {688, 944}
2014-02-10 11:36:06.101 optimisation-bug[461:60b] point: 40.000000, 40.000000
2014-02-10 11:36:06.103 optimisation-bug[461:60b] DONE
```

This is the output when running on device with *full optimisations*:

```
2014-02-10 11:44:53.975 optimisation-bug[471:60b] >>> Compiling with -Os optmisations, the code should *NOT* work as expected <<<
2014-02-10 11:44:53.977 optimisation-bug[471:60b] encodedRect: 50332672
2014-02-10 11:44:53.977 optimisation-bug[471:60b] encodedSize: 45089712
2014-02-10 11:44:53.978 optimisation-bug[471:60b] encodePoint: 2621480
2014-02-10 11:44:58.176 optimisation-bug[471:60b] rect: {{1.3464973428307575e+19, 6174053600}, {1.3464973428307575e+19, 1.2554206452792682e+58}}
2014-02-10 11:44:58.178 optimisation-bug[471:60b] size: {1.3464973428307575e+19, 6174053568}
2014-02-10 11:44:58.180 optimisation-bug[471:60b] point: 13464973428307574784.000000, 6174053568.000000
2014-02-10 11:44:58.182 optimisation-bug[471:60b] DONE
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable optimized away by compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942840/variable-optimized-away-by-compiler)

Comment: @matt As I state in the question `volatile` does prevent the optimisation from happening. But my question is "Why does the compile perform this optimisation?" Not, "How do I prevent it?"

Comment: Guessing that `SHIFT` is 32 you appear to be trying to break out two 32-bit floats from a 64-bit unsigned long long. However as you type the split out values as `ULongLong` (assumed to be `unsigned long long`) when you call `CGMakePoint` surely the compiler will do a *conversion*? Yet you seem to imply this code does work with the `volatile`, or are you just saying it doesn't optimised out the variable and not the the result is correct?

Comment: @CRD Yes, The code does work with volatile, without (and optimisations on) the compile skips the entire line `volatile CGPoint point = CGPointMake(values[0], values[1]);` returning an uninitialised CGPoint.

Comment: Have you compared the generated assembly? What you've done here looks ok. It's possible that the problem isn't what you think it is. Otherwise, it looks like a compiler bug to me.

Comment: @rjstelling - In my testing your code fails due to the automatic conversion, but then I encoded the values myself. Can you show the code you use for encoding? If I use my own encoding and then fix the decoding so it produces floats then the code works optimised without the volatile. I'm suspicious you're seeing a false error, its the encoding/decoding which is wrong not an optimised away variable, but I might be wrong...

Comment: @CRD Full source code can be found here: https://github.com/rjstelling/cgtype-encoding

Comment: @rjstelling - Using Xcode 5.0.2 on 10.8 your code works fine without the volatile. The debugger doesn't manage to show all the values, but that is not uncommon, however `NSLog` does. So something else would appear to be causing your issue. BTW I'd suggest you'd be better using `uint64` as your type rather than assuming `unsigned long long` is 64 bits. Also use a `struct` containing two fields rather than `malloc`ing and `free`ing an array of two elements - `struct`s are passed by value and you'll need no memory management.

Comment: @rjstelling Your question is entitled "Why is LLVM optimizing out the variable...", and it seems to me that the answers on the post I linked to give the kinds of circumstances under which this happens, plus they point out that the variable optimized out goes into a register and thus remains a value. "Optimize out" does not destroy the value! Thus my "duplicate" suggestion is meant to be a nudge that the problem might be something else, with the optimization/volatile being a red herring.

Comment: As @CRD noted, I've tried to reproduce this with your category, and I'm not seeing it so far, neither in output nor in the assembly. Do you have an explicit test case that fails? Is it perhaps failing only on 32-bit OSes? (CRD and I are testing on 64-bit OSes.)

Comment: @RobNapier I've discovered this is only reproducible on a device, I've updated the question and example source

Comment: I just tried your sample project on an iPhone 5 (32-bit A6) without problems. I don't have a 64-bit ARM handy right now.

Comment: @RobNapier Confirmed by [Mike Ash](https://twitter.com/mikeash/status/432850546064519170) to be only a 64-bit issue.

Comment: Thanks for complaining; please file a bug at http://bugreporter.apple.com, and note the bug number here.

Comment: @FlashSheridan "complaining"? :(

Comment: “Filing a bug” :-)  I can’t comment on unreleased versions, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issues seems to be a bug in the arm64 compiler; armv7(s) and x86 (Simulator) run the code without issue.

```
- (CGPoint)pointValue
{
    ULongLong encodedPoint = [self unsignedLongLongValue];
    ULongLong *values = [self splitEncodedInteger:encodedPoint withShift:SHIFT];

    //volatile is required to prevent optimising out
    /*volatile*/ CGPoint point = CGPointMake(values[0], values[1]);

    free(values); //clean up

    return point;
}
```

What seems to be happening is the `free(values)` line is being reordered in the optimisation phase  and run before `CGPointMake(...)` causing `pointer` to return with garbage values.

Thanks to [Mike Ash](https://twitter.com/mikeash/status/432850263854944256), [CRD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/568283/crd) and [Rob Napier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97337/rob-napier).

Comment: Wow. Thank you for sticking with this long enough to be able to track this down so specifically.