# Why doesn't Python optimize away temporary variables?

Tags: python, optimization, refactoring, python-internals

Fowler's [Extract Variable](http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractVariable.html) refactoring method, formerly [Introduce Explaining Variable](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?IntroduceExplainingVariable), says use a temporary variable to make code clearer for humans.  The idea is to elucidate complex code by introducing an otherwise unneeded local variable, and naming that variable for exposition purposes.  It also advocates this kind of explaining over comments..  [Other languages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/942855/673991) optimize away temporary variables so there's no cost in time or space resources.  Why doesn't Python do this?

```
In [3]: def multiple_of_six_fat(n):
   ...:     multiple_of_two = n%2 == 0
   ...:     multiple_of_three = n%3 == 0
   ...:     return multiple_of_two and multiple_of_three
   ...:

In [4]: def multiple_of_six_lean(n):
   ...:     return n%2 == 0 and n%3 == 0
   ...:
```

```
In [5]: import dis

In [6]: dis.dis(multiple_of_six_fat)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 BINARY_MODULO
              7 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
             10 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             13 STORE_FAST               1 (multiple_of_two)

  3          16 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
             19 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
             22 BINARY_MODULO
             23 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
             26 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             29 STORE_FAST               2 (multiple_of_three)

  4          32 LOAD_FAST                1 (multiple_of_two)
             35 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    41
             38 LOAD_FAST                2 (multiple_of_three)
        >>   41 RETURN_VALUE

In [7]: dis.dis(multiple_of_six_lean)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 BINARY_MODULO
              7 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
             10 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             13 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    29
             16 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
             19 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
             22 BINARY_MODULO
             23 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
             26 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
        >>   29 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because Python is a highly dynamic language, and references can influence behaviour.

Compare the following, for example:

```
>>> id(object()) == id(object())
True
>>> ob1 = object()
>>> ob2 = object()
>>> id(ob1) == id(ob2)
False
```

Had Python 'optimised' the `ob1` and `ob2` variables away, behaviour would have changed.

Python object lifetime is governed by reference counts. Add [weak references](https://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html) into the mix plus threading, and you'll see that optimising away variables (even local ones) can lead to undesirable behaviour changes.

Besides, in Python, removing those variables would hardly have changed anything from a performance perspective. The local namespace is already highly optimised (values are looked up by index in an array); if you are worried about the speed of dereferencing local variables, you are using the wrong programming language for that time critical section of your project.

Comment: Nice simple example, but wonder if there's one that looks more like a feature than a bug.  It undermines your argument to say those should produce different results.

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone: it is **one example** of behaviour that illustrates why binding matters. There are many more, but they take more time to construct and explain.

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone: the point is that the feature exists, and if Python were to decide that `ob1` and `ob2` can be optimised away, then you'd have a bug because the behaviour changes when you do that.

Comment: You're using the argument "Python isn't meant to be fast".  But the ultimate success of the language hinges on both it's real applications being fast, and its source code being comprehensible.  I'm trying to point out one (current) situation where these trade off.  You have answered my question by explaining why it would be hard for the compiler.  But you come close to implying it's impossible and undesirable when it's neither.

Comment: Optimization that changes behavior is not optimization; it's a bug.  I agree the compiler would need to be smarter than that.

Comment: BTW why in the world should two objects instantiated in the same expression be identical?  Why should that first example be true??

Comment: Yes, it is impossible for the compiler to optimise away the temporary variables, because the compiler cannot know what the types are going to be at runtime. `n` could be a type that implements the [`__mod__`  special method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__mod__) for example, which means that *more code* is going to be triggered at that point. That's the issue with a dynamic language like Python, any optimisations like these have to happen at *runtime* instead. That's what PyPy is trying to achieve.

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone: the objects are *not* identical. Instead, object id values are *reused*; the value is only guaranteed to be unique *for the lifetime of the object*. Because there are no references to the object in the first example after taking the object id, the object is cleared and the id can be reused for the second object.

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone: so by creating references to the two objects, we ensure that they are not cleared. With their lifetimes overlapping, they each have a unique id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72848/discussion-between-bobstein-visibone-and-martijn-pieters).

Answer (score 2):

[Issue 2181](http://bugs.python.org/issue2181) (optimize out local variables at end of function) has some interesting points:

- It can make debugging harder since the symbols no longer
  exist. [Guido says only do it for -O.](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-February/077193.html)
- Might break some usages of `inspect` or `sys._getframe()`.
- Changes the lifetime of objects. For example `myfunc` in the following example might fail after optimization because at the moment Python guarantees that the file object is not closed before the function exits. (bad style, but still)

  ```
  def myfunc():
      f = open('somewhere', 'r')
      fd = f.fileno()
      return os.fstat(fd)
  ```

  cannot be rewritten as:

  ```
  def bogus():
      fd = open('somewhere', 'r').fileno()
      # the file is auto-closed here and fd becomes invalid
      return os.fstat(fd)
  ```
- A core developer says that "it is unlikely to give any speedup in real-world code, I don't think we should add complexity to the compiler."